# Is there any Javadoc spell checker?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I wonder whether a Javadoc spell checker exists somewhere in open source? Would be great to have it pluggable as Maven plugin, but even a standalone binary distribution will work.

Comment: It's not the same as a standalone plugin, but if you use Eclipse there should be spell-checking support built in.  I remember disabling it in frustration not long ago because it would catch spelling errors not just in Javadoc, but in variable and function names in my source code as well.

Comment: Don't know if this helps you (since you asked for maven or standalone), but Eclipse has spell checking for JavaDoc builtin. It has to be enabled from the preferences.

Comment: Standalone plugin is what I'm after. I'm interested to check spelling during automated build cycle..

Comment: IntelliJ has a built in spell checker.  The problem with an automated spell checker is that Javadoc tend to have alot of technical terms and made up words.  You need to be able to interactively correct these or add them to a dictionary.

Comment: @yegor256 You say you want it as part of an automated build cycle... Are you expecting it to automatically correct spelling mistakes as part of the build? Because that seems error-prone to me...

Comment: @Jonathan I'm expecting it to automatically detect spell check problems and fail build cycle when any of them are found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually is at least one library that does that: [Spell Check Doclet](http://www.softframeworks.com/etc/spellcheck/SpellCheckDoclet.html)

**Plain Javadoc usage:**

```
javadoc  ^
   -doclet      spellcheck.SpellCheckDoclet ^
   -classpath   "c:\Javasoft\j2sdk1.5.0_06\lib\tools.jar;" ^
   -sourcepath  "c:\Work\dev" ^
   -docletpath  ".;c:\Tools\jazzy-0.5.2\jazzy-core.jar" ^
   -subpackages "jpdf" ^
   ^
   -echo on ^
   -checkHtmlFiles ^
   -dictionary  "/Tools/jazzy-0.5.2/dict/english.0" ^
   -dictionary  "/Tools/jazzy-0.5.2/scowl_dict/american-words.10" ^
   -dictionary  "/Tools/jazzy-0.5.2/scowl_dict/american-words.20" ^
   -dictionary  "/Tools/jazzy-0.5.2/scowl_dict/american-words.35" ^
   -dictionary  "./files/dictionary_java.txt" ^
   -dictionary  "./files/dictionary_jpdf.txt" ^
   -ignoreContaining "_" ^
   -ignoreContaining "." ^
   -echo off ^
   -ignoreFile  "./files/ignoreWords_html.txt" ^
   -ignoreFile  "./files/ignoreWords_gui.txt"
```

Now you just need to

1. [install](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) or [deploy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) that
   library to your local repository
2. translate the above parameters to
   [`javadoc:javadoc` mojo
   parameters](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html)

Comment: Inspired by this answer, I have created a pom file that allows spellchecking of Javadoc from Maven. See https://github.com/Jmcleodfoss/maven-javadoc-spellchecker.

Comment: I'm impressed with just how awful the experience is in this area.